# Something is preventing incoming connections in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, apache-http-server, webserver

I want to test Apache on my PC. When I visit my site from my PC at 127.0.0.1 or by typing my IP, it works. But when I try viewing my site from another PC by typing my IP, the site didn't load.

I only see some data transfer activity on the PC on which the site is hosted. Note, I have tried installing different server software, disabling firewall and creating a connection as incoming connection, but nothing works.

Comment: What happens if you use the other PC and type `telnet webserver_PC_IP 80`? If it does connect, try entering `HTTP/1.1` or `GET /index.html HTTP/1.1`

Comment: check your vhosts.conf and httpd.conf sites so you can check on what exactly sockets Apache is listening. Also if you have skype on - it automatically catches the 80 port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible reason of the problem is ISP. Some ISP block incoming connection to a client by blocking connection to specific port like '80' or by other methods. To solve this problem either change the port on which server is listening, contact your ISP or try changing your ISP.